# C++ ConanPacketManager ошибка при загрузке libmysqlclient 8.0.17

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, sfml, conan

При загрузке скрипт conanfile.py валится с такой ошибкой:

```
C:\Users\Dolba\Desktop\CarServiceInformationSystem\cmake>conan install -s build_type=Debug ../scripts
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Debug
compiler=Visual Studio
compiler.runtime=MDd
compiler.version=16
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

libmysqlclient/8.0.17: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
libmysqlclient/8.0.17: Trying with 'conancenter'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt completed [0.44k]
Downloading conanfile.py completed [10.74k]
Downloading conan_export.tgz completed [0.36k]
Decompressing conan_export.tgz completed [0.00k]
libmysqlclient/8.0.17: Downloaded recipe revision 0
openssl/1.1.1n: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
openssl/1.1.1n: Trying with 'conancenter'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt completed [0.18k]
Downloading conanfile.py completed [39.30k]
Downloading conan_export.tgz completed [0.29k]
Decompressing conan_export.tgz completed [0.00k]
openssl/1.1.1n: Downloaded recipe revision 0
ERROR: openssl/1.1.1n: Cannot load recipe.
Error loading conanfile at 'C:\Users\Dolba\.conan\data\openssl\1.1.1n\_\_\export\conanfile.py': Unable to load conanfile in C:\Users\Dolba\.conan\data\openssl\1.1.1n\_\_\export\conanfile.py
  File "c:\users\dolba\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dolba\.conan\data\openssl\1.1.1n\_\_\export\conanfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    from conan.tools.microsoft import is_msvc, msvc_runtime_flag
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_msvc' from 'conan.tools.microsoft' (c:\users\dolba\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\conan\tools\microsoft\__init__.py)
```

Рецепт выглядит так:

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class Libraries(ConanFile):
    name = "Libraries"
    settings = "os","compiler","build_type","arch"
    generators = "cmake","cmake_find_package"
    requires = [("sfml/2.5.1"),("libmysqlclient/8.0.17")]
```

Если изменить строчку:

```
requires = [("sfml/2.5.1"),("libmysqlclient/8.0.17")]
```

на:

```
requires = [("sfml/2.5.1"),("libmysqlclient/8.0.17"),("openssl/1.1.1n")]
```

То ничего не меняется. Не знаю куда копать, буду благодарен за помощь.